# Css Error "GET /static/%20style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 - Using Pycharm 3.8.1

Tags: html, css, flask, pycharm, http-status-code-404

I have spent almost a day trying to figure out why my css file will not work with my html file. All of the stack overflow answers did not work for me.

I would appreciate any help I can get at this point. I'm running python 3.8.1 with flask installed, and using pycharm.
[Click here to see my file structure screenshot,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOGAA.jpg)
 Here is the main **python** file code:

```
 from flask import Flask , render_template, 



app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')  
def index( ):
    return render_template("index.html" )  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run( debug=True)
```

Here is the **index.html** file code I would like the CSS to display on

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <h1> Title </h1>
<h2>Second headline</h2>
    <body>This is an orange test6</body>
</head>
<body>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {{ url_for('static', filename=' style.css') }}">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the error that I see when I run the file in pycharm:

"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
 "GET /static/%20style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Here is the CSS code:

```
h1{
    color: yellow;
}
body {
    color: orange;
}
h2 {
    color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra spaces

```
href=" {{ url_for('static', filename=' style.css') }}">
      ^                               ^
```

The second one is causing the problem. The first one is just bad form.

Comment: I see something different after I run the program : "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: You've advanced to a different problem. Is there a `static/style.css` in your project?

Comment: Yes sir, I have a static/CSS/style.css  in that order.

Comment: CSS in caps? If so, you need `filename='CSS/style.css'`

Comment: ok , thanks for the heads up, still not working but I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I would like to point out.
Firstly, you have a trailing comma where you import, sometimes it messes the program.
Secondly, try to specify the sub directory CSS in the url_for and remove the space at the beginning of the filename, that fixed my problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', 
filename='css/style.css') }}">
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tips, but it is still not working.

Comment: @BrianC Sounds weird, could you please show me what error you get exactly after using my link tag? because I built the same folder-tree like you and it works fine

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 21:12:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2020 21:12:56] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your index.html file.

1. You have two < body > tags, and one of them is swallowed by your < head > tag.
2. The link to your css is in your second < body > tag. Very weird programming you did there.

This should work, I just tried it using your [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOGAA.jpg) as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='CSS/style.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Title </h1>
    <h2>Second headline</h2>
    <p>This is an orange test6</p>
</body>
</html>
```